# Assign Fetch output to another variable in VueJS 3 / Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api

I am new to VueJS. I am sure it's something very silly and I am just unable to understand.

I was playing around with API fetch. The API returns the data as expected. However I am unable to assign it to a new variable. I understand it's because of the async await, which gets executed after the component is mounted. But I want to assign the data from the fetch to a local object variable with some other values along with data from fetch. Below is the component logic:

```
<script setup>

import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import AppDaySelector from "./AppDaySelector.vue";
import MealPrepAPI from '../api/MealPrepAPI.js';

const mealPrepSummary = ref({});
let weekdays = {};

onMounted(() => {

    let fetchStatus = 'S';
    const loadMealPrepHP = async() => {
        mealPrepSummary.value = await MealPrepAPI.index();
        // weekdays = {name: "something new", value: mealPrepSummary.value.api_data} // This is not working. Getting undefined.
    };

    loadMealPrepHP().catch(error => {
        alert("Error fetching summary from REST API : " + error);
        fetchStatus = 'E';
    });

});

</script>

<template>
    <pre>{{mealPrepSummary}}</pre>  <!-- This return the value because it renders after the data from api is loaded -->  
    <AppDaySelector :weekDays="mealPrepSummary.weeks"   ></AppDaySelector>
</template>
```

MealPrepAPI.js has the below code:

```
import { APISettings } from './config.js';


export default {


    index(){
        console.log("Inside API Call");
        return fetch( APISettings.baseURL + APISettings.summaryAPI + '1/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: APISettings.headers
        } )
        .then( function( response ){
            if( response.status != 200 ){
                throw response.status;
            }else{
                return response.json();
            }
        });
    },
}
```

I would like to assign the output of the fetch to a the variable `weekdays`. What am I doing wrong ? How can I get the value ? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried assigning the value during fetch. I even tried adding the logic in onActivated but it never gets called.

Comment: "Getting undefined" - getting where? The var is unused

Answer (score 0):

Wrong usage of async await

vue.js demo
url:https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onserverprefetch

```
onMounted(async () => {
  if (!data.value) {
    // if data is null on mount, it means the component
    // is dynamically rendered on the client. Perform a
    // client-side fetch instead.
    data.value = await fetchOnClient(/* ... */)
  }
})
```

your code

```
<script setup>

import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import AppDaySelector from "./AppDaySelector.vue";
import MealPrepAPI from '../api/MealPrepAPI.js';

const mealPrepSummary = ref({});
let weekdays = ref({});

onMounted(async () => {
    let fetchStatus = 'S';
    try{
       weekdays.value = await MealPrepAPI.index();
       console.log('res.data',weekdays)
    }catch(e){
       alert("Error fetching summary from REST API : " + error);
        fetchStatus = 'E';
    }

});

</script>
<template>
    <pre>{{mealPrepSummary}}</pre>  <!-- This return the value because it renders after the data from api is loaded -->  
    <AppDaySelector :weekDays="weekDays"   ></AppDaySelector>
</template>
```

What is the result of console?

Comment: `weekdays =` - this is a mistake here

Comment: weekdays .value = xxx；

Is that so?

Comment: Yes, seems so. Some explanation would be helpful also.

Comment: Thank you. I just read the official document of vue.js

Comment: res.data RefImpl {__v_isShallow: false, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: {…}, _value: Proxy}

Comment: @张文玉 - I managed to make it work. I set the variable as ref

`const localWeekdays = ref([]);`


then in mounted hook did this: 
`
    const loadMealPrepHP = async() => {
        mealPrepSummary.value = await MealPrepAPI.index();

        // pushing to new variable
        for(const days in mealPrepSummary.value.weeks){
            //assigning to localWeekdays variale
        }
    };
`
It seems to be working fine. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Show me the screenshot

Comment: You can write the loadMealPrepHP function outside of mounted hook  and use it

Comment: Outside also it was creating problem due to async. Thanks anyways.